# Java how to sort a list of IP Address

Tags: java, sorting

I want to sort a list of IP address in ascending order, what is the easiest way to achieve that?

For example I have these IP Address in a `List`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author myu
 */
public class SortListProject {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List addressList = new ArrayList();
        addressList.add("192.168.0.5");
        addressList.add("192.168.0.1");
        addressList.add("192.168.25.1");
        addressList.add("192.168.10.21");
        addressList.add("192.168.77.1");

        System.out.println(addressList);
    }

}
```

I would like to sort the list with the following output:

```
{192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.5, 192.168.10.21, 192.168.25.1, 192.168.77.1}
```

Comment: why not simply use a comparator converting those 4 octets to 4 bytes, then to a single int (a << 24 | b << 16 | c << 8 | d), and sort them using an ordinary int comparator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using raw-types. Please don't do that. Next, you'll need to parse the `String` representation to get `int` values from the four octets in the IP (or 192.168.100.1 will come before 192.168.2.1). You can pass a custom `Comparator` to `Collections.sort`. Assuming you are using Java 8+, they might look something like

```
List<String> addressList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("192.168.0.5", // 
        "192.168.0.1", "192.168.25.1", "192.168.10.21", "192.168.77.1"));
Collections.sort(addressList, (a, b) -> {
    int[] aOct = Arrays.stream(a.split("\\.")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
    int[] bOct = Arrays.stream(b.split("\\.")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
    int r = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < aOct.length && i < bOct.length; i++) {
        r = Integer.compare(aOct[i], bOct[i]);
        if (r != 0) {
            return r;
        }
    }
    return r;
});
System.out.println(addressList);
```

Comment: The call to `String.split()` compiles a new `java.util.regex.Pattern` every time. You should just keep a constant pattern object for doing these splits as an optimization.

Comment: Will this same solution work for IPv6 Addresses if I split by a color instead of a period?

Answer (score 1):

You can sort with `Collections.sort`, for example:

```
List<String> addressList = new ArrayList<>();
addressList.add("192.168.0.5");
addressList.add("192.168.0.1");
addressList.add("192.168.25.1");
addressList.add("192.168.10.21");
addressList.add("192.168.77.1");

Collections.sort(addressList, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        String[] ip1 = o1.split("\\.");
        String ipFormatted1 = String.format("%3s.%3s.%3s.%3s", ip1[0],ip1[1],ip1[2],ip1[3]);
        String[] ip2 = o2.split("\\.");
        String ipFormatted2 = String.format("%3s.%3s.%3s.%3s",  ip2[0],ip2[1],ip2[2],ip2[3]);
        return ipFormatted1.compareTo(ipFormatted2);
    }
});
System.out.println("sorted: " + addressList);
```

**Output:**

```
sorted: [192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.5, 192.168.10.21, 192.168.25.1, 192.168.77.1]
```

Comment: Please don't use raw types in collections; use generics instead.

Comment: I doubt this is what OP really needs. Where do you think `192.168.250.1` would belong?

Comment: `System.out.println("sorted: " + addressList);` this will just print the list address ?

Comment: You're sorting the list alphabetically, that's certainly not what the OP wanted...

Comment: @shmosel, You're right, I did not consider that option. I updated the answer.

Comment: It works in my case and I think this is the shortest solution. Thank you.

Comment: @MinwuYu `System.out.println("{192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.5, 192.168.10.21, 192.168.25.1, 192.168.77.1}");` also works in your case. But that's not very useful, is it?

Comment: @shmosel You are absolutely right. I'm new to Java, I will need to check what Collecations class can do in a minute :).

Comment: @MinwuYu My comment was said in context of the original answer. This version looks like it could work. Pretty clever too.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way is to use a `comparator` and `generics` (as outlined by folks earlier). Note that there is a fallacy of accepting the input data as being absolutely according to what you expect. For example in the case of IPs: `127.0.0.1` and `127.0.0.01` are both accepted by the Java Socket APIs. But the sort that you write should take care of these considerations as well. Therefore I recommend you to use a sorting based on the bytes (octets) of the ip address.

There are a lot of examples doing that and I would not go into that. A simple search would lead you to one on this very website.

What I would do instead is to demonstrate the need to sort by octets:

```
byte[] ipAddr1 = new byte[] { x1, x2, (byte) 010, x4 };
byte[] ipAddr2 = new byte[] { x1, x2, 9, x4 };
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByAddress(ipAddr1);
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByAddress(ipAddr2);
```

Both of these are accepted by the Java Socket library without it reporting any errors. They both work but if you sort it without taking into consideration of the individual octets (do a string sort for example) then the result might not be what you expect. Try it out and see.

For example (if you follow a `Collections.sort(list)` approach): if you have: "192.160.010.1" and "192.160.9.1". You would see the former appear as less than the latter but that is not true. The reason is that this will do a sort based on strings. That has nothing to do with the structure of an IP address.

Comment: I did not realized this problem. Thanks for sharing. You made me a better programmer.

Comment: In that case, you might uptick the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way in which you can sort the List and the other answers provide a solution to it. However, you should take a step back and think about what you're actually doing with the list.

The list is a *raw type* and there's nothing stopping anyone from adding any type of object into it. you should *always* use generics and avoid raw types.

```
List<String> addressList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Thank you, I will remember that from now on.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using Guava's `Ordering` utility:

```
addressList.sort(Comparator.comparing((String s) -> Arrays.asList(s.split("\\.")),
        Ordering.natural().<String>onResultOf(Integer::parseInt).lexicographical()));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main{
 public static void main(String[] args){
List<String> addressList = new ArrayList<String>();
addressList.add("192.1.1.100");
addressList.add("192.1.10.1");
addressList.add("192.100.10.1");
addressList.add("192.100.10.10");
Collections.sort(addressList,(a,b) ->{
    int[]aOct = Arrays.stream(a.split("\\.")).mapToInt(Integer:: parseInt).toArray();
    int[]bOct = Arrays.stream(b.split("\\.")).mapToInt(Integer:: parseInt).toArray();
    int r = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<aOct.length && i< bOct.length; i++){
        if(r !=0){
            return r;
}}
    return r;
});
 System.out.println(addressList);
 }}
```

Comment: Hello, a little context of your code can be appreciated.